# Definition of Range as Minimal Interval Containing Codomain

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, terminology

I am studying *continuous functions where the domain is some interval* (which may or may not be bounded, closed, etc). I am thinking about how continuity is related to other function properties, especially bijectivity.

Surjectivity is subjective (since it depends on how we define the range). I am curious if there is a natural way to define the range perhaps *as the minimal interval containing the codomain*. If we define the range in this way, then we can say, for example, bijectivity implies continuity.

Does this reasonable or is this being overly restrictive?

Thank you,

Matt

Comment: I think you mean letting the codomain be the minimal interval containing the image (which is what is usually meant by the range)?  The codomain is the target set, while the image (range) is the set of those values actually obtained.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to define; the "range" (better, default codomain) for continuous functions only, or for all functions? If you want to interpret "bijective" as "injective and surjective to the default codomain defined by the above definition" then in order for "bijectivity implies continuity" to mean anything, your definition must not be restricted to continuous functions. Anyway "bijectivity implies continuity" will always be false, unless you are (implicitly) assuming continuity. Bijectivity is unrelated to continuity.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. In my class, we define "range" to be the set the function maps to and the "codomain" to be the image of the function (i.e. set of values in range of f such that there exists a value in the domain that maps to it). I think the terminology we are using might be the reverse of what other use. Should I change this?